# Why is axios not post not working properly with react/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, post

In my react client, I have a form, and when user types something in, it goes into the state and it works correct. But when I try to click submit, it's supposed to do an axios post, This is the function that gets called when I click on submit

```
handleSubmit(event) {
        axios.post('/api/newBlog', this.state.title)
            .then(res => console.log("Dog"));
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

It also doesn't print out "Dog", it just goes straight to the route.
In the express route, I have this code:

```
app.post('/api/newBlog', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body);
    });
```

But when it does a console log, it prints out "undefined". And when I print out just req, without the .body, it prints out a huge object without any of the data I passed in. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.state.title` is not an object, which is what `axios.post` is expecting, it's (I presume) a string. 
 
`axios.post('/api/newBlog',{ title: this.state.title })...` should work.

Comment: Awesome, that totally worked, I also put in my entire state in and that also worked

Comment: Glad to hear. You should probably accept this answer if it solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

actually, i figured out in my index.js file for the backend, i didn't have body-parse used at all. Completely forgot that it's needed